# db.collectionNames doesn't work in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections

I want to check if a collection exist in Node.js. I use the db.collectionNames to get the names list in the db but nothing happened. The code:

```
connectDB(DBURL).then(function(db) {
        console.log('db connect ok');

        db.collectionNames('test', function(err, collectionNames) {
            console.log('get collection names');

            if(err) console.log(err);
            else console.log(collectionNames);
        });

    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

The `connectDB(DBURL)` is a promise object, it works perfectly. The output:

```
app-0 try to connect db
app-0 db connect ok
```

You can see there's nothing output from the function in `collectionNames`. I have no idea why.

I can get the collections name in Mongo shell by `db.getCollectionNames`:

```
> db.getCollectionNames()
[ "system.indexes", "test" ]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you using >2.0 version of the driver?

If so, you will need to use [listCollections instead](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/changes-from-1.0/) - this is one of the changes in the update from 1.x

Something like:

```
db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, collections){
    //collections = [{"name": "coll1"}, {"name": "coll2"}]
});
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks. I'm using the latest driver. I was reading the https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/contents.html , can't believe it doesn't mention this update. Where can I read the latest document of the node drive?

Comment: The link in my answer will take you to the changelog for the 1.0 to 2.0 transition.  The site you are on is the correct one, but you are looking at the 1.4.9 docs.  Take a look at the 2.0 docs on the same site, for example: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Db.html