# nodejs MongoDB issue - not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to run this to check of the collection actually exists:

```
dbo.collectionNames("users", function(err, names) {
    console.log('Exists: ', names.length > 0);
});
```

But it keeps telling me `'collectionNames'` is not a function

How can I do this check?

Comment: dbo ? please provide it in question.

Comment: what is your mongoose version  and mongodb driver version? if using mongoose.

Comment: dbo is just:  var dbo = db.db("myDatabase");

Comment: @monroe2019 this is answered here and will help you... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214175/db-collectionnames-doesnt-work-in-node-js

Comment: I need to check a specific named collection not if there's any collections

Comment: I think its the issue of dbo. Just try with `db.collectionNames `

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you want to know that? I ask because you can do operations with `db.collection('name')` even if it doesn't exist yet. Also show exactly how you are creating `dbo`.

Comment: Basically, when the application runs I want to insert a document into a collection but ONLY if the collection is empty, otherwise it would keep adding everytime to application runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using >2.0 of the Mongo driver. If so please use, *dbo.listCollections*

```
dbo.listCollections().toArray(function(err, colls){
   let myCollection = colls.find(coll => coll.name === 'users');
   console.log('Exists: ', myCollection?'Yes': 'No');
});
```

Edited: The above code should work.

Comment: This would not allow the OP to know whether **a specific collection exists or not**. It will only list existing collections.

Comment: @Lix, I believe he can check for the required collection from colls array. And also number of collections from colls array lenght. Don't you agree?

Comment: None of the links tell me how to check a collection by name

Comment: I donno, what difficulty you are findind. The below code should return you the desired if collection exist.


       dbo.listCollections().toArray(function(err, colls){
          let myCollection = colls.find(coll => coll.name === 'users');
          console.log('Exists: ', myCollection?'Yes': 'No');
       });